# What is the permission of writing to usb device in android 4.4?

Tags: android, permissions, usb, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to delete files and write files to usb device in android 4.4, but with the permission as follow, it is not ok:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

what is exactly of the permission?

Comment: maybe missing `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />` ?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />` to my project, but it can not delete files

Comment: what shown in logcat?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira it returns nothing. In fact `file.delete()` do not throw exception

Comment: then its not permission problem. add your question the code for delete file or try to debug your code

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I can delete the file in android device,but can not delete files in usb device, so I think I have no permission to delete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70531/discussion-between-roger-and-randyka-yudhistira).